# How can I get the content of an input in my form through JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, variables

I have a codebit where I'm making a form. There is one numerical input, and I want to know how to get that input and store it in a variable for JS calculation. How can I take the current value in the input on submit and make it a variable?

```js
$(Document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type='submit']").click(function() {

  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' />
  <script src='script.js'></script>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Classified</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Classified</h1>
  <form action="script.js" name="classified" method="get">
    <input type="number" name="classified" min="0">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
  <h3 hidden>Classified</h3>
  <h3 hidden>Classified</h3>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you use a framework such as AngularJS?

Comment: uh, your document is 'Document'.  I believe it is case sensative as 'document'.

Comment: @IgnacioVillaverde so based on what the OP wants to achieve here you recommend him to use an entire *framework*?

Comment: @Taplar the Snippet syntax highliter recognizes it, so I think it's ok.

Comment: @SidneyLiebrand It wasn´t an answer to his question, just a comment. Many people keep writing code without knowing the benefits of using a framework. jQuery is not recommended for keeping large apps maintainable. I made that question because maybe his app was larger than what he asked and a framework could solve many future problems.

Comment: Might be an obvious question but you are importing the jQuery library somewhere...right?

Comment: @IgnacioVillaverde You have a valid point but such recommendation from just this? A framework isn't the answer to everything either - just a structured way to do your things you'd most likely want to do. If his app is anything except large it will probably cause more overhead than good :)

Comment: @DaveKaye I think my software auto-imports it?

Comment: If it does that's the first I've heard of it.  HTML usually has to make an explicit reference to any external code on which it relies (as you do here with 'style.css') unless it's running in a very specialized server environment.   When you run this code in a browser do you get errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: @SidneyLiebrand I agree with you. However, I would try to never include that type of code in my apps. Basically its not clean and tidy, difficult to mantain. I suspect this is a typical case where at the begining is considered unnecessary a framework but then while growing the app, refactoring is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are allowed to change the markup of the form I would suggest giving it an ID e.g.

```
<form action="script.js" name="classified" method="get">
    <input id="my-id" type="number" name="classified" min="0">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Then in your JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type='submit']").click(function() {
        var myNumVal = $('#my-id').val();
    });
});
```

jQueries [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) methods return the `value` property of form elements.
Also, as stated in the comments below your post - I also believe `Document` is case-sensitive and should be `document` to atleast be safe that your code is actually running.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function() {
    //user could hit enter in the input field, bind on submit instead
    $("form[name='classified']").on('submit', function() {
        var $classified = $('input[name="classified"]');
        console.log($classified.val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var inputField = $("input[type='number']");
```